# Android app for forcefully turning off screen after timeout

Tags: android

I'm looking for an android app where I can configure a timer and when this time is expired the app should blacken/turn off the screen of the phone.

Maybe the app can also show a message just before that but that is optional.

No root should be needed.

Comment: As far as I know apps don't have the permission to shutdown Android. That only works on rooted devices.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'd adjust the question.